# Не получается стилизовать input type="file" не подхватывается плагин jquery.fileinput.min.js

Tags: jquery, input

Решил я попробовать стилизовать `input type="file"` для своего проигрывателя. Нашел разные статьи и решил прибегнуть к самому простому способу через `jquery` Но почему-то стандартная кнопка `Выберите файл` и `файл не выбран` все равно отображаются. что я делаю не так подскажите.
Пробовал разный порядок следования скриптов в `index.html`
Если порядок такой

```
<script src="app.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput/3.1.0/dist/jquery.fileinput.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="file" name="mediafile" />
    <button id="replacement" class="btn"></button>
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at app.js:1
```

Если поставлю app.js последним в списке:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput/3.1.0/dist/jquery.fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Выдает следущее:

```
app.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fileinput is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:2)
    at f (jquery.js:1026)
```

Если напрямую код из `app.js` пропишу в `index.html` как написано в источнике `https://github.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput/3.1.0/dist/jquery.fileinput.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- //<![CDATA[
        $().ready(function() {
          $("input[type=file][name=mediafile]").fileinput($("#replacement").remove());
        //]]>
        </script>
```

Появляется ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` в строчке, где заканчивается скрипт `</script>`

Вот содержимое `app.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=file][name=mediafile]").fileinput($("#replacement").remove());
});
```

Вот файл `style.css`:

```
.fileinput:hover, .fileinput.hover {
    color: #ff00ff;
}

.fileinput:focus, .fileinput.focus {
    color: #00ff00;
}

.fileinput:active, .fileinput.active {
    color: #ff0000;
}

button.btn {
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background:#fff url(img/choose_a_file.png) no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Почему он не цепляет плагин `jquery.fileinput.min.js` пожалуйста подскажите?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - JQ не подключен
Когда просто вставляли в html, что за комментарии сверху? <!-- //<![CDATA[
name=mediafile
А какое name у Вашего input?

Comment: input name="mediafile"

Comment: Честно - не знаю что CDATA значит, вот отсюда взял https://github.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скрипт не нужен там

```
<label id="replacement" for="mediafile"></label>
<input style="display:none" id="mediafile" type="file" />
```

а в стилях настроить #replacement как кнопку

Comment: Да Павел! Именно так и реализовал. Смотрю Вы тоже здесь зарегистрировались!